# Here i m trying to get complete data of authorized user to profile after login. tell me how to get user data in middleware

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Middleware**
my database is MYSQL and i m using sequelize. i tried findByPK() but that was not working

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    if(token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
        if(err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.email = decoded.email;
        next();
    })
}
```

**contoller**`enter code here`

```
export const loggedUser = async (req, res) => {
  res.send({ "user": req.user })
}
```

Comment: From what you provided, it's not clear what you've tried or what problems are comming up. This information is needed to help out

Answer (score 0):

just call the middleware like this :

```
router.get('/getUser', verifyToken, loggedUser);
```

So frst parameter is the end-point's name, second is your middleware, third is your controller function

Comment: i tried this, but it didn't give me all data of user.

Comment: What i'm seeing from the middleware that you are returning user.email only !
`req.email = decoded.email`, so you'll have access to email like this :
`const { email } = req;`
Then you can fetch the needed data based on it !
@VellyDevelopers